# What does "synchrotron emission from relativistic electrons in equipartition with a ∼1.5 mG magnetic field" mean?

Tags: accretion-discs, sagittarius-a, thermodynamics, synchrotron-radiation

I've heard of the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) in the context of thermodynamics.

But I don't understand how either "synchrotron emission" or "relativistic electrons" can be in "equipartition with a ∼1.5 mG magnetic field".

Does it mean that the energy density stored in the magnetic field is equal to (or is equilibrated with) the energy density of the relativistic electrons and/or the synchrotron radiation that they produce?

The phrase is from a block quote in [this extensive & thorough answer to Nature and mechanism of the short-term variability in radio strength of Sgr A*?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43198/7982) citing F. Yusef-Zadeh (2017) [ALMA and VLA observations of emission from the environment of Sgr A*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02750)

I see "energy density" half-way through the paragraph below, so I think I may be on the right track, but this is over my head:

> 4 DISCUSSION
>
> 4.1 Low Extinction Millimeter Halo
>
> [...]The millimeter halo is coincident with the X-ray emission around Sgr A*, which is dominated by bremsstrahlung arising from a medium with n<sub>e</sub>∼150 cm−3 and T∼3×10<sup>7</sup> K. The bremsstrahlung contribution at 230 GHz, about 0.2 µJy, is negligible. Thermal continuum from dust can also be ruled out because of the halo’s extinction deficit of 0.5 magnitudes at H-band relative to its surroundings. The millimeter emission could, however, be produced by synchrotron emission from relativistic electrons in equipartition with a ∼ 1.5 mG magnetic field. The energy density of each of these components would then be ∼ 10% of the thermal energy density of the hot gas, so this is plausible. The luminosity in the mm is $4 \pi d^2 \nu S_{\nu}$ ∼1.4×10<sup>33</sup> erg s<sup>−1</sup>, comparable to the X-ray luminosity, LX ∼1×10<sup>33</sup> erg s<sup>−1</sup>, implying that synchrotron cooling is marginally the dominant cooling mechanism for the gas. The synchrotron cooling time is ∼1000 yr, cf. the hot gas cooling time ∼10<sup>5</sup> yr, so this requires electron acceleration on this time scale.

Answer (score 1):

It would mean that the kinetic energy density of the electrons was equal to the energy density of the magnetic field.

Comment: Oh my goodness I've parsed the sentence differently than you, that's the problem! "X from Y in equipartition with Z"  I read it as "X (from Y) in equipartition with Z" but it's "X, from Y *which is* in equipartition with Z". Yes this solves it. *Thanks!*